# How to Insert into a Varchar Column when your data contains a Single quote?

Tags: sql, sql-server, insert

I am having an issue when trying to mass insert a number of records into a table. As the data is variable and over 3000 rows it is hard for me to identify where this will occur before trying to insert.

Below is the query i am running and how i have structured the insert:

```
Insert Into dbo.TruElectric([TruType],[MPAN],[MSN],[Address_1],[Address_2],[Address_3])

Values('SI','1030066607770' ,'S10EH00771' ,'Flat F' ,'15 Homeland Road' ,'King's Lynn')
```

Where the problem is coming is with `[Address_3]` as the name King's has a single quote in it. It recognises the single quote as the close to the open.

What is the best way around this? Is there something other than single quotes i can use?

Comment: Double the single quote:  `'King''s Lynn'`.  The double single quote is how you escape a single quote in a string in SQL.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Is there something you could recommend to help identify where there is single quote to add another?

Comment: Where is the data coming from? Is this something like a spreadsheet or csv, that SSIS or the SSMS Import wizard could do for you, rather than generate 3000 insert statements yourself....

Answer (score 0):

Use parameters to handle single quotes and prevent SQL injection vulnerabilities.

EG

```
Insert Into dbo.TruElectric([TruType],[MPAN],[MSN],[Address_1],[Address_2],[Address_3])
Values(@TruType,@MPAN,@MSN,@Address_1,@Address_2,@Address_3)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are dealing with multiple single quote and not sure where it is appearing, you can change the [**QUOTED_IDENTIFIER**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-quoted-identifier-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to **OFF** for time being.

```
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF;
Insert Into dbo.TruElectric([TruType],[MPAN],[MSN],[Address_1],[Address_2],[Address_3])
Values('SI','1030066607770' ,'S10EH00771' ,'Flat F' ,'15 Homeland Road' ,"King's Lynn")
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON;
```

*Here you can use double quote for enclosing the string.Please go through the link I had shared above because for some cases you cannot set the `QUOTED_IDENTIFIER` to `OFF`.*

[***Check Sample Demo Here***](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=1285845007c76b638b70148da6ea8051)